# Is Appsync/GraphQL a good solution for real-time display of reduced S3-based time series data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, graphql, aws-appsync

I have JSON files containing time series sample data being fed into S3. I have a React client with a component that needs to show an up-to-date statistical average of the sample data from the last x minutes.

Ideally the updates would be triggered by S3 upload rather than the browser needing to poll a webservice. Websockets and Server Sent Events are not an option. Can I practically use AWS Appsync's subscriptions to provide real-time data, given these requirements?

I'm not opposed to using an intermediary database if needed. I assume it will be beneficial for the step of querying data for a time range to calculate the average, and I assume I would trigger Lambda with S3 and use it to pull the S3 object data into the DB.

Amazon announced the addition of [Local Resolvers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/new-aws-appsync-features-and-whitelist-removal/) in February

> For example, a Lambda function could invoke GraphQL mutations to AWS AppSync in response to some event that takes place, such as processing data that’s uploaded to an S3 bucket

That sounds promising except I can't find any examples involving Local Resolvers and Lambda/S3. The only documentation I could find is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-local-resolvers.html).

**EDIT:**

Having done some reading on GraphQL I learned about the API and it seems I should be able to use an HTTP client in lambda to do mutations. Tried this with curl and it worked:

```
curl -X POST \
   https://censored.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql \
   -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
   -H 'x-api-key: censored' \
   -d '{"query": "mutation CreateEvent {createEvent(name: \"testName\", when: \"Now\", where: \"here\", description: \"testDescription\") {name when where description}}"}'
```

With this I figure I can now call an "addIntervalData" mutation via Lambda to add each S3 object's contents to a database and use a lambda resolver to implement "getAverage" and do the averaging calculation. Seems like a good direction?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds possible - what you would do is have a Lambda function that does a GraphQL mutation to AppSync, with that mutation using the `@aws_subscribe()` directive to notify clients who a subscribing. Then to trigger that Lambda function you would use an S3 event source to invoke it. Here is a tutorial for that: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html

Comment: The second part is fine - but how do I "have a Lambda function that does a GraphQL mutation to AppSync"? The one tutorial I can find is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-lambda-resolvers.html

...but it is intended to be called from AppSync with a callback function that does the actual mutation. If an S3 event is the caller this callback won't be provided.

Comment: @davegravy it's just a standard GraphQL mutation in NodeJS (or another language if you have a GraphQL client) like you would from any client. So the S3 event would invoke a Lambda and the Lambda would do the mutation. One possibility might be to use AWS Amplify API category to do the mutation: https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/media/api_guide